# Reverse Polish Notation with a Single Variable

Tags: perl, rpn

I've already written code that can perform the following conversions to an input string

```
3(7x-1)+10x-4+3x=90x+1
(3*(7x-1)+10x-4+3x)-(90x+1)
37x1-*10x+4-3x+90x1+-
```

But now, I'm a little stuck with this last one. I know how to write the code to solve RPN without an X involved. However, I'm not sure how to parse this with the x'es involved.

EIDT: I have fixed the incorrect RPN error, and it now reads

```
3 7 x * 1 - * 10 x * + 4 - 3 x * + 90 x * 1 + -
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Besides the code that got me to where I am above, not much. I'm worried that this isn't going to work at all because of the x's.

Comment: 7x is no more than the same expression (as an array) `[ '7', 'x', '*' ]` which of course binds tighter. `[3,7,x,*,1,-,*,...]`

Comment: For your comment down in ikegami's thread, how you can deal with x is to consider 7x a *dimensioned* 7. IF you can earmark all the terms with the same dimension, you can compress them into a single term. A dimensioned term could be [ 7, 'x' ], and you would just have to create logic to handle numbers, operators and array refs which give you one number, in slot 0 and one dimension, in slot 1. You're stack might be `[3,[7,'x'],1,'-','*',[10,'x'],'+',4,'-',[3,'x'],'+', [90,'x'],1,'+','-']`

Answer (score 3):

> *parsing this RPN string is what I'm worried about.*

The whole point of RPN is that it doesn't require any parsing. You can work with the output of the tokenizer directly.

```
sub get_next_token {
   /\G \s+ /xgc;

   /\G \z         /xgc && return [ 'EOF' ];
   /\G ( [0-9]+ ) /xgc && return [ NUM => $1 ];
   /\G ( [a-z]  ) /xgc && return [ VAR => $1 ];
   /\G ( [*+\-] ) /xgc && return [ $1 ];

   die("Syntax error\n");
}

my %ops = (
   EOF => sub { my $token = shift; ...; return 0; },
   NUM => sub { my $token = shift; ...; return 1; },
   VAR => sub { my $token = shift; ...; return 1; },
   '*' => sub { my $token = shift; ...; return 1; },
   '+' => sub { my $token = shift; ...; return 1; },
   '-' => sub { my $token = shift; ...; return 1; },
);

for ($rpn) {
   while (1) {
      my $token = get_next_token();
      my $op = $opts{$token}
         or die("Internal error");
      last if !$op->($token);
   }
}
```

---

Note that you don't have valid RPN.

```
(3(7x-1)+10x-4+3x)-(90x+1)
```

should result in

```
3 7 x * 1 - * 10 x * + 4 - 3 x * + 90 x * 1 + -
```

but you have

```
37  x   1 - * 10 x   + 4 - 3 x   + 90 x   1 + -
```

You're missing some multiplications, and you merged `3` and `7` into `37`.

Comment: Thanks! I finally fixed my RPN code so that I now have: $VAR1 = '3';
$VAR2 = '7';
$VAR3 = 'x';
$VAR4 = '*';
$VAR5 = '1';
$VAR6 = '-';
$VAR7 = '*';
$VAR8 = '1';
$VAR9 = '0';
$VAR10 = 'x';
$VAR11 = '*';
$VAR12 = '+';
$VAR13 = '4';
$VAR14 = '-';
$VAR15 = '3';
$VAR16 = 'x';
$VAR17 = '*';
$VAR18 = '+';
$VAR19 = '9';
$VAR20 = '0';
$VAR21 = 'x';
$VAR22 = '*';
$VAR23 = '1';
$VAR24 = '+';
$VAR25 = '-'; Now I just need to stop splitting decimals over 1 digit, and then I'll get to work implementing what you wrote above.

Comment: You have `1` and `0` instead of `10`, and `9` and `0` for `90`, and you need to replace the empty strings with `*`.

Comment: I pressed enter accidentally before I could add the last line (it was edited while you were reading it)

Comment: This is the problem: /[\d+\(\)\+\-\*\/\.]/g    I thought \d+ would match more than one decimal...

Comment: Fixed it with a much more complex regex

Comment: Okay, I completely understand get_next_token, and I like how the loop checks for 1 until end of file is reached and 0 is returned. I've personally never used a hash with subs, but I understand how its working. I imagine that in get_next_token you could also just && do {...}. However, I'm still not understanding how this can take care of the x's in my (now corrected) RPN string.

Comment: A long sequence of `if`s requires doing many comparisons.  A dispatch table reduces that to one lookup

Comment: Re "I'm still not understanding how this can take care of the x's in my (now corrected) RPN string.", what do you mean? What's suppose to be taking care of x, and what does it mean to take care of x?

Answer (score 2):

> *I'm not sure how to parse this with the x'es involved.*

Seems like you've written a parser which handles grammars of the following form:

```
stmt : expr '=' expr

expr : sum  

sum  : prod '+' sum
     | prod '-' sum
     | prod

prod : term prod
     | term

term : '(' expr ')'
     | NUM
```

All you need to change is `term`.

```
term : '(' expr ')'
     | NUM
     | VAR
```

Comment: My parser basically adds * when it is implied, removes (), binds numbers and X's together (when they are together), and then converts it to RPN format. I'm trying to solve for X (I started off with an equation and moved everything to the left). When going using the RPN algorithm, I'm not sure how to handle that very first situation in my OP example -- subtracting 1 from 7x. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by changing to term.

Comment: Your program might do that, but the parser is the code that assigns meaning to tokens. There appears to be a bug in it. You didn;t show your parser, so I can't tell you where the bug is.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, I've written code that splits things up like that. Actually parsing this RPN string is what I'm worried about. Now that I really think about RPN, I'm not sure putting it into this format was a good idea with an x involved.

Answer (score 1):

[Math::RPN](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::RPN):

> ```
>  use Math::RPN;
>  $value=rpn(expr...);
>  @array=rpn(expr...);
> ```
>
> expr... is one or more scalars or lists of scalars which contain
>     RPN expressions.  An RPN expression is a series of numbers and/or
>     operators separated by commas.  (commas are only required within
>     scalars).

Comment: Thanks! But I'm trying to avoid pre-made modules.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from ***learning*** from the techniques used in other modules.

Comment: I did look at Math::RPN, and it is my understanding that it does not handle variables (x)?